# Pointer automatically gets initialized to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers

Today I came through a strange situation where my uninitialized pointer is automatically initialized to NULL.

**Sample Code**

```
class A
{
public:
  A(): ptr1(NULL) {}

  void Fun()
  {
     if (ptr2 != NULL && ptr2->Status())
     {
        ...
        ...
     }
  }

private:
  XYZ* ptr1;
  ABC* ptr2;
};
```

When I integrated my code with existing project its started crashing at the if condition because of the wild pointer(ptr2). Then I reverted my code and put a break point at the constructor and I can see this pointer(ptr2) is initialized with NULL!!!. How this happens, nobody initialized this pointer and it was running in different PCs(Ubuntu) without any issue for past 1+ years?

Comment: Undefined behaviour includes appearing to work.  You just happened to get a zero in memory where `ptr2` was allocated.

Comment: Which pointer are you talking about ? `ptr2` ? Why would that be bad  for `ptr2` to be initialized with `NULL` ? What other value would you expect ? Just initialize it with that one rather than leaving it uninitialized.

Comment: You can't determine by inspection whether something was initialised. A pointer that accidentally has the value that represents a null pointer will look like a null pointer (and using its value is undefined).

Comment: Some debuggers and environments try to be helpful/safe by initializing memory to 0. You just got unlucky.

Comment: @RichardCritten , nwp , molbdnilo I was surprised to see this behavior after my change! same environment, same compiler only few classes added in another part of the program, seems like they doesn't like my code :(

Comment: @Caninonos its ptr2, which is not initialized in contructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ptr2` is indeed not initialised by the constructor, unlike `ptr1`.

So the behaviour on reading the value of that pointer (let alone *dereferencing* it) is *undefined*. One manifestation of that undefined behaviour is your compiler setting it to `nullptr` for you, another one is crashing.

It's time for you to change your constructor to

```
A(): ptr1(nullptr), ptr2(nullptr) {}
```

Comment: ... or use member initializers: `XYZ* ptr1 = nullptr; ABC* ptr2 = nullptr; `

Answer (score 2):

Reading the value of an uninitialized pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Pointers are uninitialized by default (in many cases), however it's possible they get a `NULL` by chance. Generated code in release mode and debug mode could be different and this is the reason you saw different behavior.

Try to initialize them in the constructor:

```
A() : ptr1(0), ptr2(0) {}
```

Moreover, it is interesting to know that you've trapped in a [***Heisenbug***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Comment: UB unless that variable is a `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Interesting. What's the different behavior for chars? I'm a C programmer not C++, and find this surprising.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The various `char` types are not allowed to have trap representations.

Answer (score 1):

> How this happens, nobody initialized this pointer and it was running
>   in different PCs(Ubuntu) without any issue for past 1+ years?

There are several possible reasons why your application has worked for such a long time.

- Some compilers/runtimes initialize all memory to zero in debug builds. Maybe you have changed your compile flags?
- When your application requests additional memory pages from the operating system these are often cleared to zero to prevent leaking arbitrary data from previously run applications. See [VirtualAlloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows which states

  > Memory allocated by this function is automatically initialized to
  >   zero.
- You may have updated some memory allocator which now works slightly different.

Code with undefined behavior can still run flawlessly under certain conditions until these conditions change.

Comment: IIRC MSVC in debug mode initializes all memory to **not** zero. There are a few different patterns like `0xFEEEFEEE`, depending on the source of that memory. You might be confused by Windows, which **does** initialize memory to zero.

Comment: I think MSVC used to initialize at least some memory to zero in debug builds, but not any more, so you're right. The behavior might still change depending on the compiler, runtime and compile flags used.

Comment: Also static and thread_local variables are always zero initialized, [\[dcl.init\]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#10)